# How do you render HTML using Java?

Tags: java, html-rendering

I am working on building a web browser in Java. I have used a parser (JTIDY) to parse the HTML page into a DOM document. I know that rendering means the graphical representation of DOM document. But I don't know what the engineering process is for HTML rendering in Java. In Java there is a JEditorkit to parse and render, but it is not well-formed. So I want a better solution.

My question is: what is the actual process of HTML rendering and showing the complete web page  in Java?

Comment: Why are you doing this? Maybe there is some easier way around the problem.

Comment: I am developing a web browser in java.At-first I was using cobra api to parse and render it.It can compile the java-script contents.But now I am having a problem to add cookie to browser.Cobra has no cookie facility.I could not access the URL-Connection from outside of the api for sending cookie to server.So I thought to render it by myself.But many people said it is not a good idea because it is a huge task.So I am confused.If you have any suggestion please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try either the [Cobra renderer & parser](http://lobobrowser.org/cobra.jsp) or [Flying Saucer project](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/).

Comment: cobra now at https://github.com/lobobrowser/cobra

Comment: flying saucer now at https://github.com/flyingsaucerproject/flyingsaucer

Answer (score 0):

There is the pretty much vaporware JWebPane that is part of JavaFX, but who knows when and if that will ever come out.

You can use [MozSwing](http://confluence.concord.org/display/MZSW/Home;jsessionid=84B6D14F5C97F45089A1BEDC2658B661) which integrates the Mozilla rendering framework with the Java Swing toolkit.